# Fillrate Issues on Android Emulator

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm getting very low framerate with OpenGL ES. If the model is far from the camera I get like 35 fps, but if it fills entire screen (say, a skybox) I'm getting 6-8 fps. It even happens when rendering a skybox alone and nothing else.

Is that actually an issue with the emulator? I'm using Windows XP SP3 on a AMD Athlon 64 Dual Core 3800 2Ghz, with 1 Gb RAM.

Comment: Bear in mind that an Android device usually has OpenGL hardware acceleration. The emulator does not, regardless of the capabilities of the underlying PC.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator doesn't use any hardware acceleration AFAIK, so it can get quite slow at times. Especially with blending and in other fillrate taxing situations, like yours. Have you tried running your project on an actual device? I'm guessing it will perform better on a phone.

Disclaimer: My experience with the emulator so far is on a very dated Athlon XP machine, so with current PCs it probably is much faster -- on my PC it's practically unusable.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it on a real device yet. 

Didn't expect this really, J2Me emulators always ran way faster than the actual phones.

Comment: Because they're not full emulators, they're actually simulators. Android's emulator emulates an ARM CPU, which requires a lot of processing power from the host machine. I personally would rather have a "slow" emulator rather than a fast one. That way, if my app is usable on the emulator, I know it's going to be good on devices :)